# PHPStorm not launching

Tags: java, ide

Here is a very strange situation...I installed the PHPStorm and if i use the terminal and type: `/opt/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh`

The IDE open and works normally.
I tried to launch the PHPStorm on the main menu in Ubuntu. So i created the jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop file in /usr/share/applications:

```
[Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0
 Type=Application
 Name=PhpStorm
 Icon=/opt/phpstorm/bin/webide.png
 Exec=/opt/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh
 Comment=Develop with pleasure!
 Categories=Development;IDE;
 StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

I have checked the permissions and all `.desktop` files have the same permissions.The phpstorm was working good before, this problem appeared after that i updated my java version.
I was using the openjdk7 and i update to java 8.
Follow the java versions that i have on my laptop:

```
Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java             100       manual mode
```

When I use the option number 2 (the new java version that I updated) I get this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1842)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:96)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:280)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:266)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

For me dont make sense because i have checked the files and the file `libawt_xawt.so:` exist and is on the right path.Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!!
I just run the command `chmod a+x` in the file `jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop` and he started the IDE normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on Menu >> Configure
2. Click on Open The Menu Editor
3. Select Programming >>Phpstorm >>Properties
4. Change the Command to snap/phpstorm/38/bin/phpstorm.sh %f

You can locate the path to your installation by typing in sudo locate -b phpstorm.sh